# Upgrade from Windows 7 to 8.1 using the upgrade assistant with an MSDN subscription

Tags: windows-8, upgrade, windows-8.1, windows-8-upgrade

I have an MSDN subscription, and want to use this to upgrade from Win 7 to 8.1; however, the upgrade assistant doesn't allow me to enter a product key - I simply get an option to buy Windows.

Is there a way to persuade Windows that I already have a key during this process?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have an MSDN subscription, go to your downloads page, download the ISO, burn to disc or USB and upgrade.

If you don't want to risk one of your activations getting used, try a GVLK during the install.  It won't activate you, but will allow you complete the install.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj612867.aspx

Comment: This is what I ended up doing; although when the Developer Preview version came out I upgraded from Win7 to Win 8.0 and it retained my programs and settings; this ended up being a virtually clean install.  Feels like a step backwards.

Answer (score 0):

Can you skip it? If so, you can input the product key after the installation.

Right click start menu - System - Change Product Key

Comment: No - you can't skip it

Comment: @pm_2 Do you install win8 from win7 or boot the disk to upgrade?

Comment: Trying to install from Win 7